# PhantomJS with Selenium returning a HTML "Not Found" page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm writing a python script to scrape a website.
I've set up selenium to use PhantomJS() because I was having issues with reading the PATH var with firefox.
This is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

I get this error code when running it:

```
> line 58, in __init__
>     desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 92, in __init__
>     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 179, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 236, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 163, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(value) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE HTML
> PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.
> org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE> <META
> HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html;
> charset=us-ascii"></HEAD> <BODY><h2>Not Found</h2> <hr><p>HTTP Error
> 404. The requested resource is not found.</p> </BODY></HTML>
```

Not sure exactly what's going on.. has anyone else ran into this issue and have a solution?

Comment: What `phantomjs` version are you using? What is the output of `phantomjs --version` command?

Comment: It's version 2.1.1!

Comment: Okay, what about `selenium` package version?

Comment: That would be `3.0.1` installed through `pip`. I'm using python 2.7 btw